# For which $x$ is $2^{x+1}-2 \equiv 0 \pmod{29} \quad and \quad 2^{x+1}-4 \equiv 0 \pmod{28}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

In
$$2^{x+1}-2 \equiv 0 \pmod{29} \quad and \quad 2^{x+1}-4 \equiv 0 \pmod{28}$$
How can I find for which $x$ this holds true. $x$ is a positive integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$2^{a+1}\equiv 2 \pmod{29}$ is equivalent to $2^a\equiv 1\pmod{29}$, because $\gcd(2,29)=1$.

$2^{a+1}\equiv 4\pmod{28}$ is equivalent to $2^{a-1}\equiv 1\pmod{7}$.

The system is equivalent to $\begin{cases}\text{ord}_{29}(2)=28\mid a\\\text{ord}_7(2)=3\mid a-1\end{cases}$, now use Chinese Remainder Theorem to conclude $a=84t+28$ with $t\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$.

It's simple in this case: let $a=28k$ with $k\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$. Then $3\mid 28k-1$ iff $3\mid k-1$ iff $k=3t+1$ with $t\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$, so $a=28(3t+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question,
$$2^{x+1}-2 \equiv 0 \pmod{29} \quad and \quad 2^{x+1}-4 \equiv 0 \pmod{28}$$
or
$$2^{x} \equiv 1 \pmod{29} \quad and \quad 2^{x} \equiv 2 \pmod{14}$$
or
$$2^{x} \equiv 1 \pmod{29} \quad and \quad 2^{x-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$

By Fermat's Theorem, we have that 
$$2^{28k} \equiv 1 \pmod{29} \quad and \quad 2^{6l} \equiv 1 \pmod{7}$$ for any $k,l \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comparing we can say that 
$$x=28k \quad and \quad x=6l+1 \,  \forall \,  k,l \in \mathbb{N}$$

Can this prove to be of any help? I will be glad if it does.

Comment: @user236182 Typo corrected.

Comment: You've only found some solutions, but not all of them. Indeed $\text{ord}_{29}(2)=28$, but $\text{ord}_7(2)=3\neq 6$, though it's true that $\text{ord}_7(2)\mid 6$, so you've found at least some solutions.